# How to implement arctan function in Java?

Tags: java

#### Function to implement

[image: here is the function]

#### Code

```
public class arctan {
    public static double arctan(double x) {
        double sum = 0;
        int k = 0;

        double arctan1 = (Math.pow(-1, k) * (Math.pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / (2 * k + 1)));
        for (int i = k; i < 100; i++) {
            sum =+ arctan1;
        }
        return (double) arctan1;
    }
}
```

#### Issue

My program just gives back my `x` as output. I don't see the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Just what do you think the value of `arctan1` is inside your `for (int i = k; i < 100; i++)` look?

Comment: `+` is redundant in `sum =+ arctan1;`. You probably wanted `sum += arctan1` but that still wouldn't work as you wanted since changing `k` wouldn't change *already calculated value* held of `arctan1`. You need to recalculate each time in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `double arctan1 = (Math.pow(-1, k) * (Math.pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / (2 * k + 1)));` in the loop as well since that is what the Σ is doing in the formula.

You also didn't need to have a new variable `i` in the for loop in this case. Using `k` like the formula is fine.

So it would be like this instead:

```java
public class arctan {
    public static double arctan(double x) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; i++) {
            sum += (Math.pow(-1, k) * (Math.pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / (2 * k + 1)));
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What does the letter Σ (sum over) mean?

See Wikipedia about the mathematical sum-symbol (uppercase sigma in Greek alphabet): [Σ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%A3).

In you case it is the sum over a range from `k = 0` until `k = infinite`.

The sum of the *term following* the sigma.

#### Define it as function instead variable

The *term following* is implemented correctly by:
`double arctan1 = (Math.pow(-1, k) * (Math.pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / (2 * k + 1)));`

Extract it as function of `k` and `x`:

```
public static double arctan1(int k, double x) {
    return ( Math.pow(-1, k) * (Math.pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / (2 * k + 1) ));
}
```

Because the calculation is depending on inputs `k` and `x` now, you can use it in your sum-over range of k:

```
// Note: the limit is 99 here, not infinite
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
  sum += arctan1( k,x );  // increasing k used as input
}
```

#### Put it all together

```
// your "term following the sum-over" implemented by function arctan1(int k, double x)
 
public static double arctan(double x) {
    double sum = 0;
    // your loop to sum-up for increasing k
    return sum;
}
```